# How to make different use of a contact form model with a static pages controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a static `PagesController` and a `ProjectRequestsController`, as shown below. Pretty basic. The `ProjectRequestsController` acts as a simple contact form.

I'd like to be able to identify if a project_request form has been submitted whether from one page or another, e.g, set to `true` or `false` an attribute to each project_request record when persisted.

Ex: if a form is submitted from home, set `home = true`, etc...

I tried nesting project requests resources under pages, but doesn't work as my pages do not have any ID.

I thought about passing `hidden_field` values from the form to my controller, but don't know exactly how to proceed or event if I should go down that road.

Is the best way to achieve this?

PagesController

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  # Landing pages
  def landing_one
    render 'pages/landings/landing_one/landing_home'
  end

  def landing_two
    render 'pages/landings/landing_two/landing_home'
  end  
  .... 
end
```

ProjectRequests table:

```
create_table "project_requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "title"
    t.boolean "home", default: false
    t.boolean "landing_one", default: false
    t.boolean "landing_two", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**EDITED**
Add ProjectRequestsController snippet. 
For now, it looks like this. I am rendering in a modal the form., escape JS.
So my `new` action is bound to my `new.js.erb` through which I am passing my empty shell `@new_project`.

```
class ProjectRequestsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :new, :create ]
  before_action :set_project, only: [:edit]

  def new
    @new_project = ProjectRequest.new
  end

  def create
    @new_project = ProjectRequest.new project_requests_params
    respond_to do |format|
      if @new_project.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.js
        flash[:notice] = t('controllers.projects.success')
        AdminNotificationMailer.new_project_notification(@new_project).deliver
      else
        format.html { render 'edit' }
        format.js
        flash[:alert] = t('controllers.projects.fail')
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  private

  def project_requests_params
    params.require(:project_request).permit(:name,
                                             :email,
                                             :description,
                                             :travel,
                                             :home)
  end

  def set_project
    @project = ProjectRequest.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please also add snippet of `ProjectRequestsController` as well?

Comment: Right on. Just posted it. Basically, based on each `PagesController` action, I should be able to pass a different `ProjectRequest` instance variable with an attribute corresponding to that page's  action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution,

I simply created the following helper and used it in my `create` `ProjectRequestsController` method.

`referrer` allows me to get the ancestor's URL of my new_project_request_path, and thus, get what `PagesController` method is being used.

```
  def set_new_project_instance
    project = @new_project
    if request.referrer.include? ‘home’
      project.landing_one = true
    elsif request.referrer.include? ‘travel’
      project.landing_two = true
    end
    project.save
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

First off set the flag in the action itself about the source of the form

```
def home
  @new_project = ProjectRequest.new(home: true)
end
```

Here we are setting `home: true` in case of form is rendering on home page.

Now in your form use hidden variables for each landing page flag

```
<%= form_for @new_project do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :home %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :landing_one %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :landing_two %>
  ....and your other fields....
<% end %>
```

When you submit form and pass the the parameters in `create` action, it would automatically set the page flags.

Comment: Thanks Amit, confirming my thoughts. What I did realize nevertheless is that instantiating @new_project in `PagesController` is useless here as it comes from the `new` method in `ProjectRequestsController`. Thus, it is instantiated once in this controller and I can't pass different new instances of project_requests to my form.